# How is the reflectance spectrum of solids measured?

Tags: botany, measurement, phenology

I was reading [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21829/what-determines-the-autumn-leaf-color) about autumn leaf colors. One of the answers [refers](http://www.biology.upatras.gr/attachments/article/650/Archetti%20et%20al%20Trends%20in%20Ecology%20and%20Evolution.pdf) to an article by Archetti et al. In the article, box 4 (page 5) shows the reflectance spectra of leaves of different color. How is the reflectance spectrum of such solid materials measured? There was a recent question about [spectrophotometers](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/27587/what-are-the-requirements-for-a-spectrometer-to-be-used-in-biological-research/27595#27595) but it appears to assume the sample is in a liquid form.

Answer (score 3):

As the name implies, reflectance spectra are measured from light reflected off an object. Any object with reflects light, such as any opaque object) will work for this technique; to me this seems like solids are ideally suited for reflectance spectrphotometry. You might be used to *transmission* or *absorbance* spectrophotometry, which measures the amount of light transmitted or lost after passing through a sample. These methods are typically used for liquids which allow passage of light to some extent.

[The paper (1)](http://rspb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/276/1654/121.long) cited by the review you mention says that they used a "[RAMSES-ARC hyperspectral radiance sensor](http://www.trios.de/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=196&catid=47&Itemid=76&lang=en)," which is probably just as awesome as it sounds. In principle reflection spectrophotometry works very similarly to transmission-based spectrophotometry: generate monochromatic light, shine it at the sample, and measure the intensity of light that comes back at that wavelength (or over a range of wavelengths)$^†$. If you do this for many different wavelengths of light, you have a reflectance spectrum. [This link](http://www.labint-online.com/uploads/tx_ttproducts/datasheet/principles-and-applications-ofreflectance-spectrophotometry.pdf) might have some useful information.

$^†$ **Edit**: Modern-day spectrophotometers use a more efficient method in which broad-band light is passed onto the sample and the response at a single wavelength can later be mathematically reconstructed. If you're interested in these types of details, refer to [Fourier Transform spectroscopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform_spectroscopy).

---

[(1)](http://rspb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/276/1654/121.long): Doring TF, Anchetti M, Hardie J. (2009). Autumn leaves seen through herbivore eyes. *Proc. R. Soc. B* 282(1801): 121-127.

Comment: is it really a matter of serially sampling different wavelengths? Or can you perform some kind of FFT-like procedure and analyze it all at once? (+1 nonetheless :-)

Comment: @ChrisStronks fair point. I wasn't really aware how spectrophotometers are actually built/implemented, more just the conceptual idea behind them. I can edit the answer to reflect this.

Comment: I would have given you another +1 but alas I can't. Very interesting addition (I am interested in computer vision applications but pretty newbie on the topic :-)